# Does LibGit2Sharp support atlassian stash repositories to work with

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, libgit2sharp

I have a GIT repository say "https://github.com/Myname_XXXX/TestGit". I need to traverse through all the commits of this repository and get certain information like commit author, id, message etc. I am using the below code snippet and it works fine.

```
        string repoPath = "https://github.com/Myname_XXXX/TestGit";
        GitRepositoryManager objTest = new GitRepositoryManager("Userid", "Pwd", repoPath, @"C:\ClonedFolder");

        string path = Repository.Clone(objTest._repoSource, objTest._localFolder.ToString());
        using (var repo = new Repository(path))
        {
            int i = 1;
            foreach (var Commit in repo.Commits)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("Number : {0}", i);
                Console.WriteLine("Author: {0}", Commit.Author.Name);
                Console.WriteLine("Message: {0}", Commit.MessageShort);
                Console.WriteLine("Commit Id: {0}", Commit.Id.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Commit Date: {0}", Commit.Author.When.DateTime);
                Console.WriteLine("Author Email: {0}", Commit.Committer.ToString());
                i = i + 1;

            }
            Console.WriteLine("Total Commits: {0}", i - 1);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

    }

}

class GitRepositoryManager
{
    public readonly string _repoSource;
    public readonly UsernamePasswordCredentials _credentials;
    public readonly DirectoryInfo _localFolder;

    public GitRepositoryManager(string username, string password, string gitRepoUrl, string localFolder)
    {
        var folder = new DirectoryInfo(localFolder);

        if (!folder.Exists)
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Source folder '{0}' does not exist.", _localFolder));
        }

        _localFolder = folder;

        _credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials
        {
            Username = username,
            Password = password
        };

        _repoSource = gitRepoUrl;
    }
}
```

My First question is :

1. Is there a simple way to connect to GIT repository by providing GIT logon credentails (Without Cloning-->using Repository.Clone()) : as I have used 
   in the above code snippet) and do the traversing of all the committs of a repository without cloning as it creates problem when we have huge code base
2. Does the same concept applicable to Atlassian stash (as it also based on GIT concept)

Answer (score 0):

> (Without Cloning-->using Repository.Clone())

Then you would need to use the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/), and use an approach like  "[Get github commits on all branches from API](https://bountify.co/get-github-commits-on-all-branches-from-api) "

```
for line in `curl "https://api.github.com/repos/:user/:repo/branches" | \
  grep -o '"name":.*,' | \
  sed 's/"name": "//g' | \
  sed 's/",//g'`; \
  do; \
    curl "https://api.github.com/repos/:user/:repo/commits?sha=$line" >> result.json ; \
  done;
```